# I would like to use a Chrome extension to detect the closing of a window and execute a ChromeAPI Notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension

thanks for opening this topic.

I am developing an extension for Chrome.
The goal is to detect when the browser window is closed and display a notification.

I have defined the following code in a Service Worker (background).

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.notifications.create("TEST", {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "/img/logo.png",
    title: "【Notification】",
    message: "[TEST Notification]",
    priority: 2,
    buttons: [{
      title: "OK"
    }]
  });
});
```

If you debug a Service Worker and set a breakpoint to check the process step by step, you will be notified.
However, if the browser is terminated in a normal non-debugging state, the browser is terminated before the notification is made, or perhaps the notification is not made.

Because notifications themselves are asynchronous? I have been thinking about this and other things, but have not reached a solution.
Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*manifest.json*/
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "BBB",
    "description": "bla bla bla",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "main.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["notifications", "background"]
}


/*main.js*/
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, windowInfo) => {
    if (windowInfo.isWindowClosing)
        chrome.windows.getAll(ws => {
            if (ws.length == 0) //last window
                chrome.notifications.create('BBB', {
                    type: "basic",
                    title: "bla bla bla",
                    message: "bla bla bla",
                    iconUrl: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==',
                })          
        })
});
```

Of couse the user must switch on **Continue running background apps when Chrome is closed**
under **Settimgs --> System**
**EDIT** ...and close the window(s) with the upper right X

Comment: Hi Robbi.

I was missing the idea of using BACKGROUND.
Your answer was what I was looking for.
I have successfully achieved my goal.
Thank you very much.